# Keep all plot components same size in ggplot2 between two plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like two *separate* plots. I am using them in different frames of a beamer presentation and I will add one line to the other (eventually, not in example below). Thus I do not want the presentation to "skip" ("jump" ?) from one slide to the next slide. I would like it to look like the line is being added naturally. The below code I believe shows the problem. It is subtle, but not how the plot area of the second plot is slightly larger than of the first plot. This happens because of the y axis label.

```
library(ggplot2)

dfr1 <- data.frame(
  time = 1:10,
  value = runif(10)  
)

dfr2 <- data.frame(
  time = 1:10,
  value = runif(10, 1000, 1001)  
)

p1 <- ggplot(dfr1, aes(time, value)) + geom_line() + scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL) + scale_x_continuous(breaks = NULL) + ylab(expression(hat(z)==hat(gamma)[1]*time+hat(gamma)[4]*time^2))
print(p1)
dev.new()
p2 <- ggplot(dfr2, aes(time, value)) + geom_line() + scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL) + scale_x_continuous(breaks = NULL) + ylab(".")
print(p2)
```

I would prefer to not have a hackish solution such as setting the size of the axis label manually or adding spaces on the x-axis (see one reference below), because I will use this technique in several settings and the labels can change at any time (I like reproducibility so want a flexible solution).

I'm searched a lot and have found the following:

[Specifying ggplot2 panel width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489250/specifying-ggplot2-panel-width)

[How can I make consistent-width plots in ggplot (with legends)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255579/how-can-i-make-consistent-width-plots-in-ggplot-with-legends)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/2MNoYtX8EEY

[How can I add variable size y-axis labels in R with ggplot2 without changing the plot width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22942977/how-can-i-add-variable-size-y-axis-labels-in-r-with-ggplot2-without-changing-the)

They do not work for me, mainly because I need separate plots, so it is not a matter of aligning them virtically on one combined plot as in some of the above solutions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

haven't tried, but this might work,

```
gl <- lapply(list(p1,p2), ggplotGrob)
library(grid)
widths <- do.call(unit.pmax, lapply(gl, "[[", "widths"))
heights <- do.call(unit.pmax, lapply(gl, "[[", "heights"))
lg <- lapply(gl, function(g) {g$widths <- widths; g$heights <- heights; g})
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(lg[[1]])
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(lg[[2]])
```

Comment: This does indeed work. I am so curious. Why did you not try yourself? I imagine that time is 5 seconds to paste into R but maybe you had no access to R. You were able to do all of that from memory without testing? In any case, thank you for your creative solution.

Answer (score 2):

How about using this for p2:

```
p2 <- ggplot(dfr2, aes(time, value)) + geom_line() + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = NULL) + 
  ylab(expression(hat(z)==hat(gamma)[1]*time+hat(gamma)[4]*time^2)) +
  theme(axis.title.y=element_text(color=NA))
```

This has the same label as p1, but the color is NA so it doesn't display. You could also use `color="white"`.

Comment: This is very good idea. Thank you. However I need a y label on p2. In my example I have `ylab(".")`.

Comment: I have tried to adapt the responses at here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/s5Euy1orwLY but have failed to adapt.