# Adjust space between gridded, same-sized ggplot2 figures

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I am attempting to arrange multiple ggplot2 plots into one output/grid. I'd like the plots (without considering the labels) to be the same size. I have found a way to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709307/keep-all-plot-components-same-size-in-ggplot2-between-two-plots), but now I'd like to adjust the space between the plots.

For example:
[image: example plots with default spacing]

In this plot, I'd like to reduce the amount of space between the two plots. I've tried adjusting margins, removing ticks, etc. This has removed some of the space.

[image: example plots with reduced space between plots]

Is there a way to have more control of the spacing adjustment between plots in situations such as these?

```
library(MASS)
data(iris)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

p1 <- ggplot(iris,aes(Species,Sepal.Width))+geom_violin(fill="light gray")+geom_boxplot(width=.1) +coord_flip() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) + ylab("Sepal Width")

p2 <- ggplot(iris,aes(Species,Petal.Width))+geom_violin(fill="light gray")+geom_boxplot(width=.1) + coord_flip() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_blank()) + ylab("Petal Width")


p11 <- p1 + theme(plot.margin = unit(c(-0.5,-0.5,-0.5,-0.5),"mm"))
p22 <- p2 + theme(plot.margin = unit(c(-0.5,-0.5,-0.5,-0.5),"mm"),  axis.ticks.y=element_blank())


# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709307/keep-all-plot-components-same-size-in-ggplot2-between-two-plots
# make plots the same size, even with different labels
gl <- lapply(list(p11,p22), ggplotGrob)
widths <- do.call(unit.pmax, lapply(gl, "[[", "widths"))
heights <- do.call(unit.pmax, lapply(gl, "[[", "heights"))
lg <- lapply(gl, function(g) {g$widths <- widths; g$heights <- heights; g})

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249548/side-by-side-plots-with-ggplot2-in-r?lq=1
grid.arrange(lg[[1]],lg[[2]], ncol=2) #in gridExtra
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set the 'widths' to be the maximums of the two plots. This means that the widths for the y-axis of the 'Petal Widths' plot will be the same as the widths of the y-axis of the 'Sepal Widths' plot.

One way to adjust the spacing is, first, to combine the two grobs into one layout, deleting the y-axis and left margin of the second plot:

```
# Your code, but using p1 and p2, not the plots with adjusted margins
gl <- lapply(list(p1, p2), ggplotGrob)
widths <- do.call(unit.pmax, lapply(gl, "[[", "widths"))
heights <- do.call(unit.pmax, lapply(gl, "[[", "heights"))
lg <- lapply(gl, function(g) {g$widths <- widths; g$heights <- heights; g})

# New code
library(gtable)
gt = cbind(lg[[1]], lg[[2]][, -(1:3)], size = "first")
```

Then the width of the remaining space between the two plots can be adjusted:

```
gt$widths[5] = unit(2, "lines")

# Draw the plot
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gt)
```

Comment: So this portion of the code `[, -(1:3)], size = "first")` is deleting the y-axis and left margin of second plot? And then `gt$widths` is determining the widths of the columns for the cbinded plot?

Comment: @nofunsally, Correct and correct.  The layout can be checked at any time with `gtable_show_layout (x)`.