# R: Create defined space for Y-Axis Labels and remove decimals

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a code that makes a ggplot and scales the y-axis limits based on the range of the data.  The Y-axis labels have a different number of digits, causing the plots to shift slightly to the right (the difference is slight, but present).  This creates issues when viewing the plots together, because the x-axis across the plots are offset.  I **cannot facet these plots** because the data for each plot originates from large, independent datasets that are analyzed sequentially.

1. Is there a way to create "white space" in the Y-axis label area, so that regardless of the number of digits displayed the x-axis will always occupy the same area within the figure?
2. How do I control the number of decimal places in my plot?  I only want whole numbers as axis labels.

I saw a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38722202/how-do-i-change-the-number-of-decimal-places-on-axis-labels-in-ggplot2) that addresses #2, but the responses rely on using `scale_y_continuous()`.  I adjusted my code to use `scale_y_continuous()` instead of `ylim()`, but the decimal places persist (see Plotv2.1).

I have provided a simplified example, but I think it captures the issue.  **Please keep in mind that the plots must be exported independently so faceting or using ggarrange to align axes is not possible.**

Thank you!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

df <- data.frame(
  Position=(c(1:5000)),
  Signal=(c((rep(c(-1),times=2000)), (rep(c(100),times=1000)), (rep(c(-1),times=2000))))
)

Plotv1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x=Position, y=Signal, col = "#000000")) +
  ylim(-ceiling(max(abs(df$Signal))),ceiling(max(abs(df$Signal)))) +
  coord_cartesian(clip="off") +
  guides(fill = "none") +
  guides(color=guide_legend(title="MyLegend")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_text(margin=margin(t=30)),
    legend.title = element_text(colour = "#000000", size=12),
    legend.text = element_text(colour = "#000000", size=12)
  ) +
  annotation_custom(
    grid::segmentsGrob(
      y0 = unit(-25, "pt"),
      y1 = unit(-25, "pt"),
      arrow = arrow(angle=45, type="closed", length=unit(.15, 'cm')),
      gp = grid::gpar(lwd=3, col="#000000", fill="#000000")
    ),
    xmin = 2000,
    xmax = 3000
  )

ggsave(paste("~/Desktop/Plotv1.png", sep = ""), Plotv1, width = 8, height = 1.7)

df2 <- data.frame(
  Position=(c(1:5000)),
  Signal=(c((rep(c(-1),times=2000)), (rep(c(4.9),times=1000)), (rep(c(-1),times=2000))))
)


Plotv2 <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = df2, aes(x=Position, y=Signal, col = "#000000")) +
  ylim(-ceiling(max(abs(df2$Signal))),ceiling(max(abs(df2$Signal)))) +
  coord_cartesian(clip="off") +
  guides(fill = "none") +
  guides(color=guide_legend(title="MyLegend")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_text(margin=margin(t=30)),
    legend.title = element_text(colour = "#000000", size=12),
    legend.text = element_text(colour = "#000000", size=12)
  ) +
  annotation_custom(
    grid::segmentsGrob(
      y0 = unit(-25, "pt"),
      y1 = unit(-25, "pt"),
      arrow = arrow(angle=45, type="closed", length=unit(.15, 'cm')),
      gp = grid::gpar(lwd=3, col="#000000", fill="#000000")
    ),
    xmin = 2000,
    xmax = 3000
  )

ggsave(paste("~/Desktop/Plotv2.png", sep = ""), Plotv2, width = 8, height = 1.7)



Plotv2.1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = df2, aes(x=Position, y=Signal, col = "#000000")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, nsmall = 0),
                     limits = c(-ceiling(max(abs(df2$Signal))),ceiling(max(abs(df2$Signal))))) +
  coord_cartesian(clip="off") +
  guides(fill = "none") +
  guides(color=guide_legend(title="MyLegend")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_text(margin=margin(t=30)),
    legend.title = element_text(colour = "#000000", size=12),
    legend.text = element_text(colour = "#000000", size=12)
  ) +
  annotation_custom(
    grid::segmentsGrob(
      y0 = unit(-25, "pt"),
      y1 = unit(-25, "pt"),
      arrow = arrow(angle=45, type="closed", length=unit(.15, 'cm')),
      gp = grid::gpar(lwd=3, col="#000000", fill="#000000")
    ),
    xmin = 2000,
    xmax = 3000
  )

ggsave(paste("~/Desktop/Plotv2.1.png", sep = ""), Plotv2.1, width = 8, height = 1.7)
```

[image: Plotv1]
[image: Plotv2]
[image: Plotv2.1]

Comment: Have you tried using the [patchwork](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/) package to combine the plots? That should take care of aligning the plot boundaries for you. If you only want while numbers, what should the axis labels be for the bottom two plots? So you just want labels at -5, 0, 5? Plots with just three numeric labels tend to look kind of awkward.

Comment: The data used to make the plots is not present within R simultaneously, so I don't think that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to consider using base graphics, their labels and axis positions might be more consistent, even with decimal places. We will use normalized plot coordinates (npc) in `grconvertY` to get consistent arrow and legend positions. Assuming your data is in a list "dfl" you could loop over, and the legend texts are in another list "leg", you could proceed as follows.

```
for (i in seq_along(dfl)) {
  png(sprintf('plot%s.png', i), 800, 200)  ## open png device
  par(mar=c(4, 4, 1, 9) + .1)  ## set margins
  plot(dfl[[i]], type='l', col='red', xaxt='n', xlab='Position', ylab='Signal',
       panel.first=grid(), las=1, ylim=max(dfl[[i]]$Signal)*c(-1, 1))
  axis(1, axTicks(1), labels=FALSE) 
  y <- grconvertY(c(-.25, .6), from='npc', to='user')  ## get y for arrow and leg
  arrows(x0=2000, y0=y[1], x1=3000, y1=y[1], lwd=2, xpd=TRUE, length=.05)
  legend(par()$usr[2]*1.03, y[2], title=leg[[i]][1], leg=leg[[i]][2], lty=1, 
         col='red', xpd=TRUE, bty='n')
  dev.off()  ## close png, which saves plot
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

You could also consider using `pdf()` instead of `png()` to get vector graphics.

---

*Data:*

```
n <- 5e3
dfl <- lapply(c(100, 5, 1), \(s) data.frame(
  Position=seq_len(n),
  Signal=replace(rep_len(-1, n), 2001:3e3, s)
))
leg <- list(c("MyLegend 1", "#000000 1"), c("MyLegend 2", "#000000 2"),
            c("MyLegend 3", "#000000 3"))
```

Comment: Is it possible to set the position of the Arrow using x-axis coordinates, similar to the   `xmin = 2000, xmax = 3000` in my code?  The arrow is not always in the same position, and it is important that the arrow correlate with the numerical values on the x-axis.  My example did not emphasize this requirement, and I apologize.

Comment: @JVGen Absolutely! The arguments go `arrows(x0, y0, x1, y1, ...)` so just use `x0=2000` and `x1=3000`. I use the function so often that I forgot to mention the arguments. Please see respective edit which should make that more clear. You see, you could obviously also derive these values dynamically from the data for each `i`teration. Best you read the help pages for each new function you learn; unlike user-defined packages, those from base are excellent.

Answer (score 1):

1. With `theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 10, b = 0, l = 0)))` we can tweak the position on the right side of the plot by tweaking r = 10 etc..
2. With `scale_y_continuous(labels = label_number(accuracy = 1))` from `scales` package we can control thy y axis numbers.

I use `ggarrange` to demonstrate how the plots look when plotted in one column. If you change `r` in `element_text` the alignment will change:

```
library(ggpubr)
library(scales)
Plotv1 <- Plotv1 +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 10, b = 0, l = 0)))+
  #scale_y_continuous(labels = label_number(accuracy = 0.01))
  scale_y_continuous(labels = label_number(accuracy = 1))

Plotv2 <- Plotv2 +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 16, b = 0, l = 0)))+
  #scale_y_continuous(labels = label_number(accuracy = 0.01))
  scale_y_continuous(labels = label_number(accuracy = 1))

Plotv2.1 <- Plotv2.1 +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 16, b = 0, l = 0)))+
  #scale_y_continuous(labels = label_number(accuracy = 0.01))
  scale_y_continuous(labels = label_number(accuracy = 1))
ggarrange(Plotv1, Plotv2, Plotv2.1, ncol = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi TarJae, I tried adding `theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 30, r = 10)))` and `scale_y_continuous(labels = label_number(accuracy = 1))` to my plots.  The number of decimals is now correct, but the plots still do not line up correctly.  Keep in mind that I am using `ggsave` to export the plots independently, and arranging them in image software.  I think the axes are properly aligned in your example because of `ggarange`, but I cannot use `ggarrange` because my actual data (i.e. df and df2) are not present simultaneously within R - the datasets are too large.

Comment: @JVGen. Hi the key is here: `margin(t = 0, r = 16, b = 0, l = 0)` tweal and try with different r = .... So for example you do plot2 with r = 16 and it is more right then change r to 20 to see in which and to which extend the changes take place. And all in all it is a try!

Comment: Ah, I see.  I am looking for a way to adjust it so that, regardless of the numbers on the y-axis, the space the plot/data occupies is always the same.  I know I can manually adjust each using the method you describe, but I'm looking for a way to get them to behave the same without needing to manually tweak.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the approach in https://stackoverflow.com/a/69843619/4413615 to get this working in ggplot2? Use a formatting function on the axis labels through `scale_y_continuous(labels = \(x) formatC(x, width = 6))` and change the font to fixed-width using `theme(axis.text = element_text(family = "mono"))`.  The width of 6 can be changed to the maximum width observed across your plots.

Full example on Plotv1 below

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

df <- data.frame(
  Position=(c(1:5000)),
  Signal=(c((rep(c(-1),times=2000)), (rep(c(100),times=1000)), (rep(c(-1),times=2000))))
)

Plotv1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x=Position, y=Signal, col = "#000000")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = \(x) formatC(x, width = 6),
                     limits = c(-ceiling(max(abs(df$Signal))),ceiling(max(abs(df$Signal))))) +
  coord_cartesian(clip="off") +
  guides(fill = "none") +
  guides(color=guide_legend(title="MyLegend")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_text(margin=margin(t=30)),
    axis.text = element_text(family = "mono"),
    legend.title = element_text(colour = "#000000", size=12),
    legend.text = element_text(colour = "#000000", size=12)
  ) +
  annotation_custom(
    grid::segmentsGrob(
      y0 = unit(-25, "pt"),
      y1 = unit(-25, "pt"),
      arrow = arrow(angle=45, type="closed", length=unit(.15, 'cm')),
      gp = grid::gpar(lwd=3, col="#000000", fill="#000000")
    ),
    xmin = 2000,
    xmax = 3000
  )
```